# Programming interactiv video with AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video, html5-video

For the work, I am amused to the realization of an interactive video. This means a video that proposes choices to users. Choices influence the scenario of the video. Thus, such choice refers to such a moment of the video.

I could already realized this type of video in HTML5 or with Youtube, I master the logic of the concept. Problem, this time, I need to export the interactiv video to a program without using the Web. So I thought of using Flash to compact my interactive video into a ".exe".

Nevertheless, I wish to have the opinion of the community because the gotoAndPlay function in AS3 is unstable.

So, do you have any alternatives to offer me? There are many software programs that claim to be able to create videos of this type but all are bugged.

Thanks in advance and sorry about my english !

Comment: For HTML 5 you could simply use Electron to package it as an executable. Apache Cordova is also possible. For AS3 you could use Adobe AIR.

Comment: Explain your _"gotoAndPlay function in AS3 is unstable"_... what did you try that showed it was unstable?

Comment: @VC.One my problem with gotoAndPlay is that the function is not precise. When user chose a way, I need that the video goes to a precise timecode. In my case, Flash doesn't work with precision and there is an offset with the requested timecode. I hope to be understandable !

Comment: @DodgerThud thx a lot, I'll learn and try about it !

Comment: @RomainAndré so you put video's frames on the timeline and seek with `gotoAndPlay()`?  Use **Netstream** to play a video. Inaccurate (frame) seeking is not a Flash problem, it's how decoders work. They only seek to key-frames. For example, if your video has a setting of _"Put key-frame at every 5 seconds"_ it can only seek (jump to) 5, 10, 15, 20 etc seconds. Most coders find the nearest time's key-frame bytes and feed to  decoder (but not display to user) then feed other next frame's bytes up to required timestamp (which is now displayed). It's not easy but I've done it in Flash before.

Comment: PS: Why not break your video into small clips then just play the right clip file for the user choice? Videos will play instantly since no web downloading needed.

Comment: @VC.One Breacking video into small clips seems to be a good and simple solution, I'll try it ! Thx a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

AS3/AIR is ideal to export rich media applications, but from your question it seems you lack the experience. If you start from zero, consider a book about OOP in AS3, you can find second hand very good books, since AS3 has been stable for a long while. I did all sort of video apps in AS3, from UGC composited video content, to full featured video chat apps managed from a local workstation in TV studio grabbing video from Android devices, etc. just to give you an idea of how powerful the platform is. Same kind of apps in JS require longer debug time and are less powerful (intrinsic limitations of i.e. the video object in browsers). I would go with AS3, but there are other considerations that only you can know.